# Is $f(x)= 3x + \arctan(x) + 1$ injective?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Is $f(x)= 3x + \arctan(x) + 1$ injective?

A given function $f(x)$ is said to be injective if $\forall a,b \in X f(a)=f(b) \Rightarrow a=b$

We can easily see that $D(f)=\mathbb{R} $, using the statement I've proceed by

$3a + \arctan(a) + 1 = 3b + \arctan(b) + 1 \iff$

$3(a-b) + \arctan(a)  + \arctan(b) = 0 \iff$

I'm lost from here. Couldn't think of any helpful identity.

Comment: Can you show that the function is (strictly) increasing?

Comment: Hint: You may use Rolle's theorem.

Comment: Yes, I've derived f(x) and obtained that is strictly greater than zero then is strictly increasing for all X. Then what?

Comment: You should specify the domain when asking about "injective".  For example, $x$ could range over some region of the complex plane.

Comment: HINT.-If $$3x+1+\arctan(x)=3y+1+\arctan(y)$$ then we have
$$\arctan\left(\frac{x-y}{1+xy}\right)=3(y-x)$$ Choose an arbitrary real $y=a$ so you have $$\arctan\left(\frac{x-a}{1+ax}\right)=3(a-x)$$
Show that the line $y=3(a-x)$ and the curve $y=\arctan\left(\dfrac{x-a}{1+ax}\right)$ intersects in just a point.

Since for $x=a$ you have $LHS=RHS$ and the value $a$ is arbitrary,you have
$$3x+1+\arctan(x)=3y+1+\arctan(y)\Rightarrow y=x$$ Thus the function is injective.

Comment: Have a look at [The Graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wtdmqxpoji) of the function. It says enough about its injectivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we know that the function is strictly increasing, that means that $f'(x) > 0$ for all values of x. By Rolle's theorem or the Mean Value Theorem, if $f(a) = f(b)$ for different values $a$ and $b$, then there exists a value $c$ between $a$ and $b$ such that $f'(c) = 0$. However, we determined that $f'(x) > 0$ for all values of $x$. Thus, if $a$ and $b$ are different values, then $f(a)$ cannot equal $f(b)$. Thus, $f(x)$ is injective.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for differentiation or Rolle's theorem. Since $x \mapsto 3x$ and $x \mapsto \arctan x$ are strictly increasing by themselves, so is $f$.

Hence if $x \neq y$, we may as well assume $x < y$ (otherwise switch $x$ and $y$), so $f(x) < f(y)$, which shows that $f$ is injective.